# XCode: Failed to create provisioning profile w/ Generic Device

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework

I am trying to release my ionic app for iOS but I am getting this error below when I try to archive my app in Xcode:

[image]

I have created a profile and added iOS Distribution and iOS developer certificates:

[image]

I have tried various solutions found online such as unchecking and checking Automatically Manage Signing, changing Deployment Target from 8.0 -> 7.0 and even closing and reopening Xcode.  Yes, I paid the $100 for a developer account.

I also do not have an iOS device which may be the problem.  I should be able to do this without an iOS device though right?

Also, I was following this tutorial https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/distributing-ios-apps-with-itunes-connect--cms-21672 but I got stuck at the end - It doesn't tell me what to put in here on iTune Connect:

[image]

Any help is appreciated - Thanks.

EDIT: All the 'stuff' I did:

Here is the app information I filled out as suggested by a comment (I have not submitted it yet - I believe I need to Archive it first?):

[image]

Here is my Provisioning Profile.  I downloaded it and opened it in Xcode.  I tried to archive it but I got the described error:

[image]

Heres my distribution thing (Should be in my provisional profile):

[image]

And also my key (Should be in my provisional profile):

[image]

I also have this certificate in my Keychain:

[image]

Edit Edit:

Dragging the provision profile onto Xcode didn't do anything.  I went into Xcode and manually opened it with Xcode and got this thing:

[image]

Is the file type correct?  Its called `Moment_Provisioning_Profile-2.mobileprovision`.  This is the file I got when I hit download on the above screenshot.

Comment: you dont need a device to create ipa. You can very well do the same with Generic iOS Device option. Have you downloaded the provision profile from the developer account and added it to your system Keychain Access?

Comment: @MAhipal Singh Selecting the profiles manually is not a best when just because we have trouble creating it with automatic.

Comment: @AAA :  why its not a best way? when we install the Adhoc profile we need to set it manually to resolve the error.

Comment: @AAA I created and opened the provision profile with Xcode.  I have a Developer ID Certificate in my Keychain if thats what you're referring to.  I updated my question to include everything I did - Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

first: if you have not register your bundle id in the apple developer center for your app, 
then goto **"Certificates, identifiers and profile"** section: https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action and register it after that..

uncheck  `Automatically Manage Signing,`

and select your downloaded profile : and then clean and build again.
[image]

for more about [xcode help](http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/9.0/)

**EDITED**

Step 1: Clear the derived data

Step 2: then download the provision profile & certificate from developer account

Step 3: install the certificate by double clicking on it

Step 4: drag provision profile on xcode icon in Dock. [image]

Step 5: uncheck "automatic code sigining" option  and selected the provision profile from list as shown above

Comment: I believe I did this - I updated my question with everything I have

Comment: @MatTaNg , i updated the answer..pls check and let me know

Comment: @MatTaNg pls don't drag in project: Pls check the gif i added in answer, simply drag on xcode icon on dock.

Comment: Yah I didn't drag it into my project I dragged it on top of the icon - The 'dock' (Except mines at the bottom yours is on the side).  How'd you make the gif?  Maybe I can show you what i'm doing

Comment: use GIPHY CAPTURE application from App Store . but as per your  screenshot its inside the xcode project

Comment: Well I tried and upload the giphy but the file was too large - Even as a 2 second giphy.  Regardless I pretty much did what you did and nothing happened.  My screenshot was from after I attempted dragging it onto the icon.  I opened the file itself by double clicking it.  Seems like something is wrong with my provisioning profile?

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to add your device UDID in Apple developer certificates and identifier section.
2. Recreate and install provisioning profile.
3. Make sure you are using correct app ID/ bundle identifier in your bundle settings.
4. Xcode should pick up provisioning profile automatically, if not uncheck automatic box and select your developer provisioning profile.
   Hope this will help.

Comment: I don't have a physical device

Comment: Ok. My answer holds good for developer profile which you asked earlier. For distribution or releasing app to AppStore, you don’t need physical device. If you already have created distribution certificate and provisioning profile, and it’s not appearing in Xcode, just restart Xcode and if needed Mac as well.

Comment: One more thing- before restarting Xcode, go to product tab and clean. On a side note-you can directly upload app to AppStore Xcode while following product->archive steps. It takes few mins to appear your IPA/build in iTunesConnect.